# Set child relationship to parent with parentId and get parent with all childrens in list in one transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Sample of entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event")
public class Event {

...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Event parent;

@Column(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long parentId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Event> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

In my case I need in one transaction save new childrens in DB with parentId, for example:

```
Event child = new Event();
Event parent = new Event();
parent.setId(10L);
child.setParent(parent);
repository.save(child);
```

After save many childrens i want in same transaction get parent by id and get list of his childrens:

```
Event parent = repository.getEventById(10L);
parent.getChildren();  // result - empty list
```

But get empty list, i think, it's because all changes stay inside cache and i need end current transaction and get parent with childrens in next transaction. Is there another solution besides this? Maybe there is an opportunity to do flush or something?

I make this in two transactions, but answer is: another way?

Comment: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Did you save your parent? As a side note, your parent child relation abstraction  is not correct.

Comment: It's a sample, in project things more complicated.
In sample we expect what parent saved and have id = 10L.

Comment: So, you do save the parent?

Comment: Yeah. Problem is when i get parent after save children then in parent.children i get empty list of objects, because transaction not closed.